# Can someone help me figure out why VS Code refuses to acknowledge getline as a function?

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-code, getline

I'm currently using VS Code with minGW installed. I'm trying to use getline() but no matter which libraries I include, stdlib.h, string.h, etc., it just tells me that getline has not been defined.

I was sure it must be part of string.h like it normally but I just cant figure this out. Is it often part of a different library that I just don't know about?

I've pasted a code snippet below but the code is kind of irrelevant as I'm just attempting to get getline to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "gameCharacters.h"
#include "colors.h"
#include "technicalDefinitions.h"

void printTitleScreen()
{

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t line_Buffer_Size = 'a';
    int count = 0;

    FILE *titleScreenFile;
    titleScreenFile = fopen("ASSETS/titleScreen.dat", "r");

    while (count < ARRAYMAX)
    {

        getline(&line, &line_Buffer_Size, *titleScreenFile);

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(line) - 1; i++)
        {

            if (line[i] == 'G') SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), GREENBLOCKCOLOR);
            else if (line[i] == 'C') SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), CYANBLOCKCOLOR);
            else if (line[i] == 'B') SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BLUEBLOCKCOLOR);
            else if (line[i] == 'P') SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PUKEBLOCKCOLOR);
            else if (line[i] == 'Y') SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), YELLOWBLOCKCOLOR);

            printf("%c", BLOCKCHARACTER);

        }

        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

Like I said, the compiler just tells me that getline has not been declared in this scope.

I'm new to this site so I'm not exactly sure if I can post screenshots but I can provide some if that would help.

Comment: MinGW is a port of GCC to Windows, not a complete POSIX environment (like e.g. Cygwin is). As such, it doesn't have POSIX specific functions like [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).

Comment: Besides that problem, like *all* `FILE` functions, it takes a `FILE *` argument, so you're not even calling it correctly. And you call it with an invalid initial buffer size. And you forget to check for errors from both `getline` *and* `fopen`. And you never close the file, leading to a resource leak.

Comment: Nothing here is remotely final or even really started. In fact everything besides the for-loop was copied and pasted from an older project. I just stopped working as soon as I saw that getline wasn’t available and tried to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `getline` is a non-standard function which isn't portable. It is not found in any of the standard headers, because it isn't a standard function.

(POSIX has the very bad habit of shoving non-standard crap into standard headers.)